# UWP to another app communication in same machine

Tags: .net, sockets, uwp

According to the Note in this article we cannot communicate between 2 UWP apps in the same machine using sockets. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets

I want to know whether that restriction is only for 2 UWP apps or even if I want to connect to a non UWP app (a .net app or a Windows app) from the UWP app, it'll not be allowed?

I just ran a sample .net socket server and a UWP client in the same machine and they seems to work. But I want to know whether this will work when the UWP app is submitted to Store. In some forums I have read that certain features will work in Visual studio. But not in Store version.

Even when I created a side loaded package and tested, it seems to work. So I want to confirm there is no restriction to use sockets between a UWP client and a .net server running in the same machine, before I start implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, UWP apps are running in the sandbox and they will block localhost requests because of the network isolation. And a common way we used to implement communication between UWP and Non-UWP apps is using App service.

Here is the sample about how to using app service between them:[AppService Bridge Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample)

Comment: Thanks Roy for the info. In the link you have shared, it says the project is outdated so I referred to the link given there. But I am not sure whether all those 3 options given there does what I need. We have a UWP app and another 3rd party app which has a .net plugin we have added there as a dll. Now we want to call a function in that plugin (dll) from our UWP app running on the same machine. While both are running as 2 separate applications on foreground. Can you please suggest me the best way to do that. Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, we have to call a SDK in another 3rd party app we use. For that what we did was created a .NET C# class library project which is installed as plugin in that 3rd party app/software. Our plugin works as a socket server and listen to the UWP app clients connecting and then when the client sends a message we call that SDK method from this plugin. But later saw in some threads that there is a restriction in UWP when communicating via sockets to another app (even non uwp) in same machine. So I am looking for the best way to do this. So any guidance on this is really appreciated.

Comment: Yeap the sample is outdated, but it won't matter unless you want to package the third app with the UWP together. Maybe it is confused to understand. If you don't mind, you can change it a little bit using a clearer way. You could package a win32 process inside your UWP app, using App service to communicate between the UWP app and the Win32 process. Then in the Win32 process, you could use other win32 API like Socket Class to communicate with the .net app.